# SwiftUI Core Data

Tags: swift, swiftui

When I create a new project using the SwiftUI interface and SwiftUI Life Cycle (ticking Core Data)

[image]

As soon as it sets up I run on the simulator and get a white screen.

In preview there is a populated list - but no edit button

[image]

I'm using Xcode 12 (12A7209).

How can I use the simulator, and how can I get the toolbar to work correctly?

Comment: The white screen is because there are no items stored in Core Data.  The list in preview is there because ContentView_Previews uses a preview persistence controller that fakes a bunch of items so there will be something to display.  (The rest of your question, I don't know.)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a glitch, but here is a workaround. Note: I don't know is this works on non iOS devices.

Wrap the body's contents in a `NavigationView` remove the tool bar and add code as shown here:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.timestamp, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var items: FetchedResults<Item>
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    Text("Item at \(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)")
                }
                .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
            }
            .navigationBarItems(leading: EditButton(),
                                trailing: Button(action: addItem) { Image(systemName: "plus") }
            )
        }
    }
    
    private func addItem() { /// From this line down, Apple's code works.
```

Also note that currently -- I just ran into this problem and this solution works on Xcode Version 12.3 (12C33) -- you may need to actively save your project (Command+S), quit Xcode and restart so that CoreData's auto-generated entity "Item" can be found in scope.

Answer (score 0):

This is working as expected. In the simulator, there is no data in the core data stack. So the list has nothing to show and the screen is empty. Unfortunatly the toolbar does not show.

For the preview you are using a stack with items already added. Have a look in the Persistent file. You will find a preview stack that adds the items. For all views that use the viewcontext from the environment or @FetchRequest reads you need to add the viewcontext to the preview.

```
 static var preview: PersistenceController = {
    let result = PersistenceController(inMemory: true)
    let viewContext = result.container.viewContext

    //-> adding items to show in the preview here
    for i in 0..<10 {
        let newItem = Task(context: viewContext)
        newItem.date = Date()
        newItem.content = "task with number \(i)"
    }
    
    do {
        try viewContext.save()
    } catch {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        let nsError = error as NSError
        fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
    }
    return result
}()
```

If you want to see more you can check thi